# Adding UIButton on PageViewController which is visible on the last UIImageview only

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I have done a project which is based on a food delivering app.I have added my 3 images which are there in a view controller and its a page view controller because I want my images to slide horizontally.

My main purpose of this question is I need a button to be there in the last image view.Please provide me complete code for adding a UIButton which only visible in the last image.
For Example - :

(Lets Go) is a Button which is available in the last image view.Forget about Button placement.

Advance Thanks....

My code is something like this - :

## ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource{

```
var pageViewController : UIPageViewController?
let Contentimages = ["splash","up","viewpage_bg"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    
   super.viewDidLoad()
    
   createpageViewController()
   setupPageControl()
    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func createpageViewController(){

let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self
    if Contentimages.count > 0 {
    
        let  firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewController = [firstController]
    
    
         pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewController, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
        

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}

func setupPageControl(){

    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor=UIColor.gray
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor=UIColor.white
    appearance.backgroundColor=UIColor.darkGray


}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let  itemController = viewController as! ItemViewController
    if itemController.itemIndex > 0
    {
        
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        
    }

    return nil

}
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let  itemController = viewController as! ItemViewController
    if itemController.itemIndex+1 < Contentimages.count
    {
        
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        
    }
    
    return nil

}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return Contentimages.count
}
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
func  currentControllerIndex() -> Int {
    let  pageItemController = self.currentController()
    if let controller = pageItemController as?ItemViewController{
        
        return controller.itemIndex
        
    }
    
    return -1
}

func currentController() -> UIViewController? {
    
    if (self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count)! > 0{
        
        return self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
        
    }
    return nil
}
func getItemController(_ itemIndex: Int) -> ItemViewController? {
    
    if itemIndex < Contentimages.count {
        
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemController") as! ItemViewController
        
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = Contentimages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

## ItemViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController {

```
var itemIndex: Int = 0;
var imageName: String = ""{
    
    
    didSet{
        
        if let imageView = contentImageView{
            
            
            imageView.image = UIImage(named : imageName)
        }
                    
    }
    
   
}




@IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    contentImageView.image = UIImage(named : imageName)
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: Why aren't you using UICollectionView if there is only an image and you need only swiping functionality?

Comment: Actually am a beginner can you please help me with that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `UICollectionView` to achieve this:

**1. `UIViewController` containing `UICollectionView`**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell
        if indexPath.row == collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1
        {
            cell.letsGoButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.letsGoButton.isHidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

**2. Custom `UICollectionViewCell`**

```
class CustomCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var letsGoButton: UIButton!
}
```

**3. View Hierarchy**

[image]

**4. Things to remember**

1. Don't forget to set `dataSource` and `delegate` of `UICollectionView`.
2. Set the `Collection View Flow Layout` to `Horizontal` in `Storyboard`.

Comment: Nice Explanation. A big Thank you for that, Your code is just superb and I hope it will solve my problem, will get back to you after finishing @PGDev

Answer (score 1):

You could add this button on your ItemViewController. Then make the button hidden or visible depending of current page. Something like this:

```
let  pageItemController = self.currentController()
let currentPage = self.currentControllerIndex()

if currentPage == Contentimages.count - 1 {
    pageItemController.button.isHidden = false 
} else {
    pageItemController.button.isHidden = true 
}
```

For example here (if I correctly understood your code):

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
                          viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let  itemController = viewController as! ItemViewController
    if itemController.itemIndex == Contentimages.count - 1 {
        itemController.button.isHidden = false 
    } else {
        itemController.button.isHidden = true 
    }
    if itemController.itemIndex+1 < Contentimages.count {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)    
    }    
    return nil


}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank You So much For your information.I will definitely try this.@Eridana